# OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY. can we use in sql query? or what alternate solution for this?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

oracle 12.2.9

db version 18c

we are getting .csv(comma separated) file form external source. and need to split_string into 1 TABLE type Array field and then need to insert into interface table.
but as i can see in .csv(comma separated) file amount field having "," between amount i.e "71,007,498.00"

i have this value `"71,007,498.00",0.00,0.00,"71,007,498.00"`,

so while splitting this value, it should be like

```
 lv_data_tbl := split_string('"71,007,498.00",0.00,0.00,"71,007,498.00",' , ',');
```

expected output

```
lv_data_tbl(1)=71,007,498.00

lv_data_tbl(2)=0.00

lv_data_tbl(3)=0.00

lv_data_tbl(4)=71,007,498.00
```

but getting this output:-

```
lv_data_tbl(1)=71

lv_data_tbl(2)=007

lv_data_tbl(3)=498.00

lv_data_tbl(4)=0.00

lv_data_tbl(5)=0.00

lv_data_tbl(6)=71

lv_data_tbl(7)=007

lv_data_tbl(8)=498.00
```

Answer (score 1):

I *guess* it can be done in SQL by parsing that string, but - why wouldn't you use an **external tables** feature? As it uses SQL*Loader in the background, it lets you use `optionally enclosed` parameter.

For example, this is contents of my source data (filename is `test_quotes.csv`):

```
1,"71,007,498.00",0.00,0.00,"71,007,498.00"
2,15.00,"12,332.08","8.13",2.82
```

Let's create the external table. It requires you to have access to a directory (line #11) (Oracle object that points to a filesystem directory that contains the file. If you're not sure how to get it, talk to your DBA. If there's none, say so):

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test_ext
  2  (
  3     id     NUMBER,
  4     val1   VARCHAR2 (15),
  5     val2   VARCHAR2 (15),
  6     val3   VARCHAR2 (15),
  7     val4   VARCHAR2 (15)
  8  )
  9  ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
 10     (TYPE oracle_loader
 11      DEFAULT DIRECTORY kcdba_dpdir
 12      ACCESS PARAMETERS (RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
 13                         FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 14                         (id,
 15                          val1,
 16                          val2,
 17                          val3,
 18                          val4))
 19      LOCATION ('test_quotes.csv'))
 20     REJECT LIMIT UNLIMITED;

Table created.
```

Any data?

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM test_ext;

        ID VAL1            VAL2            VAL3            VAL4
---------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ---------------
         1 71,007,498.00   0.00            0.00            71,007,498.00
         2 15.00           12,332.08       8.13            2.82

SQL>
```

Fine; it works with no effort at all. OK, *with a little bit of effort*.

---

On the other hand, you could use SQL*Loader itself - write a control file and load data. It is really, *really* fast. And - you don't have to have access to any *directory* - source file can reside on your own hard disk.

Comment: for this line need to use only below value. below 7 fields i need to insert in interface table.

"23202","00","Unvouchered Receipts","19,981.45",0.00,0.00,"19,981.45",
----------------------------------------below is actual line---------------------------------
Activity","Ending","Adjustment","Account","Subaccount","Description","Balance","Debit","Credit","Balance","Adjustment","Balance","23202","00","Unvouchered Receipts","19,981.45",0.00,0.00,"19,981.45","Total",,0.00,"3,797,240.03","4,704,188.08",0.00

Comment: @mohit - if you want to add a clarification please **edit your question**. Sample data or code is really hard to understand in a comment due to the poor layout and formatting.

Comment: first of all Thanku for the the help.-----------------------------------------------------lv_file_handle      := UTL_FILE.FOPEN(g_filepath,lv_filename,'r') ;
LOOP BEGIN UTL_FILE.GET_LINE(lv_file_handle,lv_in_rec);                                    
 v_data_tbl := split_string(lv_in_rec,',');
----------------------------------------------------------------------
above is the piece of code where we are inserting , separated values in Table type array variable. so i can use this EXTERNAL Table concept which you provided. but can we use GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE on this ? instead of normal table

Comment: You're welcome. As of a GTT - try it and see. Generally speaking, that should work. Pay attention to the way you create it (what you'll do on commit - delete or preserve data).

Comment: GTT's can be used as external tables ?

Comment: No, that's a completely different thing. GTT is a table. External table is just a "pointer" to a filesystem file (stored in a folder on a database server).

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the info. can we use this  "organization external tables" concept under any package?   if yes could you please share some sample syntax. TIA

Comment: littlefoot @Littlefoot Thanks for the info.  2 points i have...........................................................................................    
1:- can we use this external table concept inside a package?..............................................................
2:- in Line no #19 can we put runtime file name. means as per daily basis file is generating in the location with timestamp.?

Comment: #1: Inside a package? If you meant that you'd want to access that *external table* from within a packaged procedure (or a function), then yes - no problem. As of #2: filename is - as far as I can tell - *static*, so you'd have to either rename the file so that its name is always the same, or drop/create the external table on daily basis, using a different file name every time.